# How to write images from URL to PDFkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am getting a JPEG from a URL using node.js requests.
I then convert the image to a base64 buffer and write it to the pdf document:

```
request({ url: url, encoding: null }, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            var img = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
                            pdf.image(img, 0, 0);
                            callback(error, body);
                        }
                    });
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: stream.push() after EOF
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:156:17)
    at PDFDocument.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at PDFDocument._write
```

Comment: Could it be that pdf.end() is getting called prematurely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine for me.
However, here is 100% working snippet:

```
request({ url, encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));

        var img = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
        pdf.image(img, 0, 0);

        pdf.end();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

JS and `Axios` example:

```js
async function fetchImage(src) {
    const image = await axios
        .get(src, {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
    return image.data;
}

const logo = await fetchImage("https://i.imgur.com/2ff9bM7.png");
doc.image(logo, 0, 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

`TypeScript` and `node-fetch` example:

```
const fetchImage = async (src: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(src);
  const image = await response.buffer();

  return image;
};
    
const logo = await fetchImage("https://i.imgur.com/2ff9bM7.png");
doc.image(logo, 0, 200);
```

Comment: Please note that `response.buffer()` does not exist. It's called `response.arrayBuffer()`